# PHP: Object-oriented code - Class 'x' not found, but there is

Tags: php, oop, object, namespaces

I have problem with including CryptoGuard, but maybe there is my issue with object-oriented code, because I am newbie in that.

```
require_once('CryptoGuard.php'); // = https://github.com/CoreProc/crypto-guard/blob/master/src/CryptoGuard.php

$passphrase = 'my_private_key'; 
$cryptoGuard = new CryptoGuard($passphrase);
$stringToEncrypt = "private string";
$encryptedText = $cryptoGuard->encrypt($stringToEncrypt);
echo $encryptedText;
```

Easy usage of CryptoGuard example: https://github.com/CoreProc/crypto-guard (same as I used, but I do not use Composer so I just copied CryptoGuard.php).

There is no php error, but the part with cryptoGuard broke page (stop loading anymore things, no $encryptedText echo there).

Comment: Or maybe (for whatever reason) the result is just empty. Can you try `echo '>' . $encryptedText . '<';` just to make sure whether or not that statement is executed?

Comment: Hi MBaas, thanks for your reply. No, the page freeze and do not load anything more. I tested and it load just content before "$cryptoGuard = new CryptoGuard($passphrase);", nothing after that.

Comment: What is `var_dump($cryptoGuard->encrypt($stringToEncrypt));`? and is error reporting set to `error_reporting(E_ALL);`?

Comment: Hello Christian, thanks for your reply. I set error_reporting(E_ALL); and I see the error:
Fatal error: Class 'CryptoGuard' not found in code.php on line 44 (= $cryptoGuard = new CryptoGuard($passphrase);). So it looks that there is problem with object-oriented code as I thinked, but really dont know how to fix that, because require_once works.

Comment: To get sure if is CryptoGuard.php loaded correctly I added `echo "loaded";` at the end of CryptoGuard.php file and it is really loaded correctly. Very strange, where can be problem please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Problem is the `Namespace`. CryptoGuard uses `Coreproc\CryptoGuard`;

So your Code should be

```
require_once('CryptoGuard.php'); // = https://github.com/CoreProc/crypto-guard/blob/master/src/CryptoGuard.php

$passphrase = 'my_private_key';

//Not missing the Namespace here
$cryptoGuard = new \Coreproc\CryptoGuard\CryptoGuard($passphrase);
$stringToEncrypt = "private string";
$encryptedText = $cryptoGuard->encrypt($stringToEncrypt);
echo $encryptedText;
```

Alternative, your provided Code will work, if you write at the beginning of your script:

```
use \Coreproc\CryptoGuard\CryptoGuard;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I implemented object-oriented code first time, so I did not know what does "namespace" do. :)

Comment: No problem :) Everyone begins with something. Glad I can help. Namespaces and OOP are extremly powerfull, you should do more often something with it. And with a good IDE such like PHPStrom they make your development much faster.